# how to slide from one frame to another in flash CS4?

Tags: flash, adobe, cs4

Hey, I'm making a choose your own adventure interactive novel game using flash CS4. I'm able to create the basic structure but I'd like to add some transitions between frames when a player makes a choice. I want to make it look like one frame slides to the left followed by the next frame sliding into view.

Please note that I have almost no experience with actionscript.

Comment: you want to use the transform tool over many frames.

Comment: actually rereading your post you want to just change x and y positions

Comment: Another thing I would suggest. If you are a noobie Flasher a game would not be the place to start. Learn OOP first. Do some tutorials first. Create simple objects first.

Comment: if its not too much trouble, can you give me an example code that shows to change x and y position of an entire frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the X or Y of a "frame"
Instead what you need to do is create an object and position that object.
As per your request.
There is a word of issue with doing just this. Like garbage collecting the mc object after it has been pushed off the stage.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 80);
mc.graphics.endFill();
mc.x = 80;
mc.y = 60;
addChild(mc);


var timer:Timer = new Timer(5);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer );
timer.start();
function onTimer( e:TimerEvent ):void{
    mc.x = ++mc.x
}
```